# QML ListModel to string

Tags: json, qml, stringify, listmodel

I have a ListModel filled like that:

```
Component.onCompleted:{
  fillListModel();
}

ListModel{
  id:listModel;
}
function fillListModel(){
  for(var i=0; i<2; i++)
    listModel.append({"aKey": "aKey"+i})
}

ComboBox{
  ...
  model:listModel  //each element of the model appears only one time
}
```

I would like to make a string from that model so I do:

```
function listModelToString(){
  var datamodel = []
  for (var i = 0; i < listModel.count; ++i){
    datamodel.push(listModel.get(i))
  }
  var keysList = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
  console.log(keysList)
}
```

I get the following result:

```
[{"aKey":"aKey0","aKey":"aKey0"},{"aKey":"aKey1","aKey":"aKey1"}]
```

Why does it put each pair (aKey,aKey0), (aKey,aKey1) in double?
I can get ride of the "extra" values but I wonder why I get that intstead of simply:

```
[{"aKey":"aKey0"},{"aKey":"aKey1"}]
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Minimal code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
  id: mainWindow
  width: 400
  height: 400
  visible: true

  Component.onCompleted:{
    fillListModel();
  }

  ListModel{
    id:listModel;
  }

  function fillListModel(){
    for(var i=0; i<2; i++)
      listModel.append({"aKey": "aKey"+i})
    listModelToString()
  }

  function listModelToString(){
    var datamodel = []
    for (var i = 0; i < listModel.count; ++i)
      datamodel.push(listModel.get(i))

    var keysList = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
    console.log(keysList)  //output [{"aKey":"aKey0","aKey":"aKey0"},{"aKey":"aKey1","aKey":"aKey1"}]
  }

  ComboBox{
    model:listModel  //each element of the model appears only one time
  }
}
```

Comment: I get: `qml: [{"aKey":"aKey0"},{"aKey":"aKey1"}]`, 
it seems to me that you have called the fillListModel function twice or something similar, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks but it's really the minimal I can provide, all of that is in an Item and the listModel is used for a ComboBox (I updated my post). But if you have the good result, I'll check on my side. And the function fillListModel is called only one time.

Comment: if it provides a [mcve] I could copy and execute directly, it is minimal but not complete, but I still give the same answer.

Comment: Ah ok, I updated. I use Qt 5.9.0.

Comment: I keep getting a correct result, I'm testing it with Qt 5.10.1 on Linux

Comment: Ok so same code, different results, seems like a Qt issue.